# Copying files from S3 buckets in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I was wondering whether the copy module can be used to deploy my installation tarball from an AWS S3 bucket to an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [s3](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/s3_module.html) for this task:

Excerpt from examples:

```
# Simple GET operation
- s3: bucket=mybucket object=/my/desired/key.txt dest=/usr/local/myfile.txt mode=get
```

But this requires `boto` and AWS credentials on target host.

You may want to make download url with `mode=geturl` with local action and then fetch it on your target box.

Comment: Note: in ansible 2.4 the module is called [aws_s3](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/aws_s3_module.html)

Answer (score 1):

**file_root:** File/directory path for synchronization. This is a local path, 
**key_prefix:** In addition to the file path, prepend s3 path with this prefix. A module will add a slash at end of prefix if necessary.

```
- name: "copy to S3 bucket"
  s3_sync:
    bucket: your-bucket-name
    file_root: "/tmp/file.txt"
    key_prefix: Deployment
    file_change_strategy: force
    include: "*"
    permission: private
    mode: push
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/s3_sync_module.html